# Как связать диалоговое окно с tk.Toplevel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть код на `Tkinter`, состоящий из множества окон. Из каждого окна можно открыть диалоговое окно типа `askyesno`, но есть проблема - все диалоговые окна открываются в `tk.Tk()` окне, а не в `tk.Toplevel()`.

Как можно привязать диалоговые окна к окнам `tk.Toplevel`?

То есть чтобы диалоговые открывались не на фоне главного окна, а на фоне окон, из которых вызываются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был довольно простым. Оказывается у `messagebox` есть аргумент `parent`, который обозначает родительское окно на которое диалоговое должно переключиться после закрытия.